# ASP.NET MVC Razor - Datatable export issue while filtering

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, tabletools

I have been trying from couple of days to bind my view part with controller in razor style and I have done to a level well everything working cool but I'm stuck now & any clue is appreciated.

**My mvc controller returns something like**

```
public ActionResult Listings(string id)
{
// my code to build list
return View(//My List);
}
```

**In cshtml :**

```
   @foreach(WebApp.Models.PersonModel item in Model)
           {
           <tr>
               <td>@item .ContactPerson</td>
          </tr>
             }
```

I'm loading/sorting even exporting also fine with wonderful table tools but not as expected.

**Problem :** 
When I mention a search criteria like name say `jeff`, I get contact person names with `jeff` and I try to export to pdf/excel but I get all records which are loaded into datatable exported not filtered ones? Is this a bug with datatable or any thing I need to correct from my end?

**PS :** I have done filter based export when I'm using `AjaxSource` etc with controller returning JSON but now it's not the case you can clearly understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a submit when the filtering is happening. So your Model contains only the rows you want to export... 
 Or try to make a method that accepts a string and will return the desired result on a click of a button. Call the method with the filter query

Comment: sorry i believe i didnt get you in excat . data-table tools will automatically places pdf/excel buttons etc submit ? click of button ? any snippet is helpful .

Answer (score 0):

yeah i got it done small option `oSelectorOpts` set in my js file under tabletools

```
"oTableTools": {
"aButtons": [
    {
        "sExtends": "Excel",
        "sButtonText": "Excel",
        "oSelectorOpts": {
            page: 'current'
        }
    }
]
```

}

**Reference :** http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#oSelectorOpts